# C# file.delete function deletes only after main app closed

Tags: c#

basically i have a function that clears a folder from all items within it, and i have a button that activates that function, i use it in other parts of my code and it works fine, i suspect that its some problem with the media player component but i tried clearing the url and playlist and nothing works.

code goes like that,

```
private void DeleteVidBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VidPlayer.URL = null;
            VidPlayer.currentPlaylist.clear();
            ClearPath(PicPath);
```

this is the code that runs alright

```
private void DeletePicsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearPath(PicPath);
            for (int i = 0; i < imgs.Length; i++)
            {
                imgs[i] = null;
            }
            UserImgPicBox.Image = null;
```

and this is the function for clearing the path

```
private void ClearPath(string Path)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path);
            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Delete();
            }
        }
```

the only difference i can see is that in the function that works i am reading the pictures and release the access to the file immediately after and in the one which doesnt i am playing a video using a media player component.

also note, around 2nd time or maybe 3rd that i ran this code it somehow worked fine but after when i tried again and again with the same code it didnt.
i dont know if it helps somehow but if i try to press the delete button again without closing app it throws an access exception that says the file is being used, also if i try opening the video after pressing the delete button it shows that the video is corrupted and missing data.

EDIT:
i pinpointed the source of the problem, the windows media player does cause it.
i have that block of code inside a timer that looks for files in directory and picks the 1st (there should only be one) and loads it up in a media player like this:

```
string VidPath = "";
            string[] PathArr = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(PicPath, "*.mp4", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            if (PathArr.Length>0)
            {
                VidPath = PathArr[0];
            }
            if (VidPath!="")
            {
                VidScanTmr.Stop();
                VidScanLbl.Visible = false;
                DeleteVidBtn.Visible = true;
                RegDoneBtn.Enabled = true;
                VidPlayer.URL = VidPath;
                VidPlayer.Ctlcontrols.stop();
                MessageBox.Show("video successfully scanned");
            }
```

and when i comment the `VidPlayer.Ctlcontrols.stop();` line, it doesnt throws an exception when delete button is pressed again and actually deletes the video but only after the 2nd click, if i comment the `VidPlayer.URL = VidPath;` line as well, the code works as its supposed to.

Comment: also this is my first question so excuse me if i am not clear enough

Comment: Have you checked for open file handles?  The [handle.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) command line utility will show you what handles are open and who is holding them open.  Also [process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Comment: Your code seems fine. Look into the video player and make sure it is releasing all handles. You can force a file handle to be released, however, that is a bit overkill. I would see if there is a "CurrentFile" property or some other file associated property that can set to null to release the handle. How big are the files? You can always have a quick clean up task run at startup if you don't mind leaving a little clutter between application executions. Do you have a semaphore to ensure that no two instances are running, do you have a hung instance of an earlier run holding onto a file possibly?

Comment: files currently arent big but might grow a bit in the future (when app is completed, and to around maybe 5 mb so still not that much) i am sure that the file isnt handled by a former app running in background, first i did close the app properly and it shouldnt remain active somewhere, second, file is in fact deleted but that happens only when i close the app, until then its like the file is empty but still there which causes problems in my app, ill check about the processes mentioned. thx, ill be back with the results

Comment: well i tried the handle.exe file @SeñorCMasMas-ReinstateMonica sent but since its in cmd, didnt see all of it, looked under visual studio but got nothing unusual, also went through processes, didnt see anything useful, made double sure no process is left active after app is closed. ill try testing a few more things out, make sure problem lies with the mp component and see if i can reach a solution

Comment: problem as i thought is with the media player, does anybody know of a way to load up a video without using the url property, something more similar to stream or open?

Comment: i managed to find a temporary fix, by using ```VidPlayer.openPlayer(VidPath);``` i open the video player in a new window, not related to the form basically and then when i close the media player i can delete the video and reload a new one, which is basically my purpose altho, its not the way i wanted to use it, when i have some more time ill implement the fix a bit better to open up a media player and place it on the form rather than having it appear freely on the screen